# runing kafka and zookeeper inside a single container

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, continuous-integration

For software testing purposes, I need to run kafka and zookeeper alongside of my application inside a single docker container. I know I can place all components into different containers, but that is not desirable nor practical for my use case. I have a scripts that starts zookeeper and then kafka and then the app to be tested. This works fine on VMs. On the container, zookeeper starts well, but kafka neither comes up nor emits an error message. The kafka-server-start.sh script just silently terminates without leaving behind an active kafka instance.

This is a sample from one test run:

```
===============================================================================
[sndrcv_kafka.sh]: Create kafka/zookeeper instance and static topic
Creating dependency cache dir /worker/rsyslog_docker-ubuntu18-san_rsyslog/build/tests/.dep_cache
Downloading zookeeper
Downloading kafka
Kafka work-dir /worker/rsyslog_docker-ubuntu18-san_rsyslog/build/tests/.dep_wrk/kafka does not exist, no action needed
Creating dependency working directory
Starting Zookeeper instance 
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
Using config: /worker/rsyslog_docker-ubuntu18-san_rsyslog/build/tests/.dep_wrk/zk/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... STARTED
Starting Kafka instance kafka-server.properties
Starting Kafka instance kafka-server.properties, SECOND ATTEMPT!
Failed to start Kafka instance for kafka-server.properties
SKIP sndrcv_kafka.sh (exit status: 77)
```

and this happens when I do that start manually (with zookeeper already running):

```
$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon config/kafka-server.properties 
$ echo $!
$ ps aux |grep kafka-server |grep -v grep
$
```

This reproduces on many distributions and versions and so seems to be docker related.

Does anybody know how to work around this? Or at least how to get an error message?

Comment: Do you need to use `-daemon`? That's redirecting output to a separate file and `kafka-server` is not the process name